# How to use or filters

Tags: dynamics-nav-2013

I am facing an issue with dynamics nav 2013 r2.
I am trying to create a filter using the OR condition.

So let me explain the issue.

First of all there is no way to create filters with or thus if you are searching a term it has to be available in both fields.

Say i have an item with entry number field: 1234 and description field 4321
And i have an other different item having entry number field 6789 with description field: 1234.

How is it possible to get both items if i search for 1234 on both entry number field and description field?

Answer (score 0):

You can’t do it through GUI.

And there is a way to set OR-filter for only two fields through code. It is [filtergroup(-1)](https://community.dynamics.com/nav/b/navvanvugts/archive/2015/05/30/filtergroup-1). Wouldn’t rely on it.

Depending on the goal you’re trying to accomplish you might use [AltSearchField](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics-nav/altsearchfield-property). But it seems it was deprecated.

Comment: I am not trying to do it from GUI.
The idea is that we are building a web service and by passing a "search string" i would like to list all item entries that include the string in different fields

Comment: Then no hope. Nav doesn’t support full text search. You either have to do separate calls for each field or use something else (e.g. SQL)

Comment: I was already leaning towards multiple calls. I think there is no other way or either using mark the records methods but that will cause other problems. Anyways thanks for your support!